# What are the parameters passed inside groupby function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I was looking for some example code and found this project: https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/machine-learning-create-your-own-movie-recommendation-system.html . I do not understand this particular line.

```
no_user_voted = ratings.groupby('movieId')['rating'].agg('count')
```

Here `movieId` and `rating` are colunms in `ratings` data frame.

I know what a normal groupby function does but I do not understand this line. Can someone please explain what this line does?

Comment: What's confusing? the `.agg` ? did you consult the documentation? Stackoverflow should only be used after you've exhausted all other options, which is why you're possibly getting downvoted.

Comment: It is good to see that others answered your questions but I would like to know what you tried from your self before posting on SO. To be very true this is relatively trivial issue and should have been solved by yourself with little experiments and not posted on SO as a question much less you get answer in forms other than comments.

Answer (score 3):

It works the same as:

```
no_user_voted = ratings.groupby('movieId')['rating'].count()
```

it means for each value of column `movieId` (groups) count only no missing values of column `rating` by aggregate function [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html).

Difference is only `count` function is passed to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) in your code.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire - ya, your answer is correct, if no missing values. Else it is wrong.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire Although I am not the one who down voted your answers but I do feel that such questions which don't show proper research and self attempts at understanding should not be appreciated and given answer to in a proper answer form as it will only motivate them to post more such questions and will also hinder their growth.

Comment: Anyways, I am happy that @jezrael got the credits and moderators and other folks supported us.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire - ya, I think not very nice edit answer by another one.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire - Converted to community wiki - so no more credits for me.

Answer (score 1):

The line computes the number of non missing `rating` for each unique `movieId`